# PHP not getting Guzzle response as expected

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle for HTTP Requests/Responses in my PHP project.

I'm sending the following request :

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events('[some_id]')
```

which, in Postman, returns something that looks like this :

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('...')/events/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"...==\"",
    "id": "...",
    "createdDateTime": "2018-06-14T08:03:44.5688916Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-06-14T08:03:44.7407671Z",
    "changeKey": "...==",
    "categories": [],
    "originalStartTimeZone": "UTC",
    "originalEndTimeZone": "UTC",
    "iCalUId": "...",
    "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
    "isReminderOn": true,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "subject": "Created ?",
    "bodyPreview": "",
    "importance": "normal",
    "sensitivity": "normal",
    "isAllDay": false,
    "isCancelled": false,
    "isOrganizer": true,
    "responseRequested": true,
    "seriesMasterId": null,
    "showAs": "busy",
    "type": "singleInstance",
    "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=...%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item",
    "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
    "recurrence": null,
    "responseStatus": {
        "response": "organizer",
        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": ""
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2018-06-15T10:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2018-06-15T13:30:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "",
        "locationType": "default",
        "uniqueIdType": "unknown",
        "address": {},
        "coordinates": {}
    },
    "locations": [],
    "attendees": [],
    "organizer": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "...",
            "address": "..."
        }
    }
}
```

So I build my request like this :

```
$client = new Client();

$header = array(
                "Authorization" => "Bearer ".$token
);

$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events('" .$idEvent. "')";

$request = new Request("GET", $url, $header, "");

try {
     $eventInfos = $client->send($request);
}
catch (GuzzleException $e) {
     var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

But when I var_dump($eventInfos), I get a GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request object.

What is the correct way to get the JSON I was expecting please ?

Comment: try `$eventInfos->getBody()`

Comment: in the `try` block print out  `$eventInfos->getBody()` after sending the request

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex, I've answered Abhishek in the comment below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to extract the body of from the response. Try this,

```
$client = new Client();

$header = array(
                "Authorization" => "Bearer ".$token
);

$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events('" .$idEvent. "')";

$request = new Request("GET", $url, $header, "");

try {
     $eventInfos = $client->send($request);
     $response = (string)$eventInfos->getBody();
}
catch (GuzzleException $e) {
     var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But I've already tried it and I get this : object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)#1960 (7) {
  ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
  resource(1609) of type (stream)
  ["size":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
  NULL
  ["seekable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["readable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["writable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
  string(10) "php://temp"
  ["customMetadata":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}

Comment: @ThibautTang have updated the answer, the Guzzle stores the response body in Stream, so you need to typecast it to string

Comment: Works with (string) cast ! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @ThibautTang Great!! Just accept the answer and Happy Coding

Comment: Hey @ThibautTang you can still do it by this way `json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(),true)`

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use `getContents()` to get the response.

```
$request->getBody()->getContents()
```